# How do I solve 49x+99y=9999?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to solve this equation.

I want to figure out how many product I need to sell at price $x$ and price $y$ to make $\$9,999$.

I went through the $2$-step equations and inequality videos via khan academy but still no luck. I want to use what I've learned so far to solve a hypothetical question on how I can make $\$9,999$ in a year drop shipping if I sell the same product $\$49$ in spring and $\$99$ in fall.

What section of algebra should I learn to solve this equation 49x+99y=9999?

The feedback helped me understand that this equation might be what I'm after:

1) 49x+99y=10000

2) x = 5000 / 49 = ~102 sales

3) y = 5000 / 99 = ~50 sales

4) 102 sales at \$49 and 50 sales at \$99 to get \$10,000.

^ What is the right equation for the above, so I can plug in numbers to solve for it next time?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Search for _extended euclidean algorithm_ and pick a link that helps you.

Comment: Will $x=0, y=101$ be a satisfactory solution?

Comment: As this is a linear equation you have an infinite number of solutions. However, I believe you should solve with $x+y=12$ simultaneously.

Comment: Are you looking for *exactly* $\$9999$, or *at least* $\$9999$?

Comment: My equation might be wrong. I'm trying to find out how many sales I need to make at \$49 and \$99 combined to earn \$9,999. e.g., half of sales from \$49 and \$99 together to get $9,999.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485214/solving-only-using-modular-arithmetic-5x7y-1234/2485222#2485222

Comment: My equation might be wrong. I'm trying to find out how many sales I need to make at \$49 and \$99 combined to earn \$9,999. e.g., how many 1's and 2's do I get from 100 if I was given 50/1 and 50/2? Like how can I get that into an equation for the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide by $99$ to get 
$$\frac{49x}{99} + y = 101$$
We want $\frac{49x}{99} $ to be an integer, so let $x = 99$. This gives us $49 + y = 101$, or $y = 52$.

So $(x,y) = (99, 52) $ is a solution.

In addition, we could let $x = 2×99 = 198$ to get
$98 + y = 101$ or $y = 3$, so

$(x, y)  = (198, 3) $ is another solution.

Trivially, we also have $(x,y) = (0, 101) $ as a solution

These are the only solutions, as $\text {gcd} (49, 99) = 1$, so $x $ must be a multiple of $99$ for $\frac{49x}{99} $ to be an integer. But $x = 3×99$ does not work, as this will exceed $9999$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sell those products all in fall then you need $101$ of them.

If you want to sell those products all in spring then you need approximately $204$ of them.

If you want to make, as is natural, all combinations of selling both in fall and spring then calculate your spring for every fall equal to $0,1,2,3,...101$

I do not see an easy way to handle all cases all at once, because we are talking here about $102$ possible equations.